# What does "Has not been rated" imply?

Tags: present-perfect

In Wikipedia, I have seen: "The text has not been rated"
Does it imply that this is up to now?

If we wanted to say up to now, they would have written "The text has not been rated yet"?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: In fact, I realized after that my page Wikipedia was translated directly from French. In english version I do not see that.

Answer (score 2):

It means that "rating the text" has not occurred at any time in the past.  Since "any time in the past" means "until now", it does mean "until now".  There is no need for the word "yet".

Comment: We might sometimes use 'yet' for emphasis, perhaps if we expected or hoped that the thing might have happened by now.

Comment: In the sentence "the country has been invaded by soldiers", as a native speaker, does this sentence can imply past event?

Comment: @safarie 'has been' always implies a 'past event'. Britain has been invaded by soldiers, the last time was in 1797.